# Typoscript get image and Title from tt_content

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Im trying to get the Image URL aswell as the Title out of a tt_content element.
So far, i was able to get the URL to the image but i got stuck at getting the Title or something else related to that Image.

The goal is to get the Image and the Title from a random tt_content element on another Page (UID: 181) and display those.

This is what i've got so far:

```
Block.Test = COA
Block.Test {
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
    pidInList = 181
      max = 1
      orderBy = RAND()

    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
      10 = TEXT
      10 {
        field = image
      }
      20 = TEXT
      20 {
        field = title
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First: The image title field is called `titleText`. You might also be interested in the fields `altText` and `image_link`. Second: How to do this depends on the TYPO3 version. In versions >= 6.0 images are only referenced using FAL (and you would get the URL, title and stuff from the table file_reference), in older versions they are stored directly in tt_content. In these older versions you need to split the `title` field by a line break (ascii 10) to separate the titles for the different images. Same for the other fields.

Comment: What is your TYPO3 installation version ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 6.2 installation, it could be done like this:

```
renderObj = 10
renderObj {
    10 = FILES
    10 {
      references {
        table = tt_content
        fieldName = image
        uid.data = uid
      }
      renderObj = IMAGE
      renderObj {
        file.import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
      }
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
      field = title
    }
  }
```

It should work on TYPO3 7.6 too.

Comment: How to wrap that image object?